# Participles replacing sentences

Tags: grammar

"When her homework was finished, she went out to play.=

Her homework finished, she went out to play. (Coursebook key answer)"

My personal answer was: "Her homework being finished, she went out to play", but I was told that it's bookish/not common.

In terms of grammar, does that mean that a time clause in passive can only be replaced by a past participle?

Here's another example that confused me:

"Because the windows were painted shut, he could only open the door. = 
The windows being painted shut, he could only open the door. (Coursebook key answer)".

Why doesn't the key use just "The windows painted shut" and it adds "being" as well?

Comment: I agree that 'being' in sentences is quite formal. couldn't tell you why though.

Comment: Sorry that the key answer says 'being,' but it's clumsy and not just formal.